# jQuery call animation before debounce method executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, throttling, debouncing

I have a piece of code like following:

```
$('.cardButton').click($.debounce(1500, function () {
    console.log("OK");
}));
```

The  debounce in this  case works just perfectly..

However - I need to add animation function which will replace ".cardButton" element  before the debounce occurs...

Doing something like this:

```
 $('.cardButton').click($.debounce(1500, function () {
        StartAnimationLoader();
        console.log("OK");
    }));
// In this  case - animation starts as  soon as console writes out "OK" ...
```

Or like following:

```
   $('.cardButton').click(function(){
       StartAnimationLoader();
       $.debounce(1500, function () {
           
            console.log("OK");
        })
});

// When I execute code like this - there is nothing written in the console... - thus this method doesn't works
```

I need to execute animation before debounce occurs ...

What am I doing wrong here?

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Comment: Give us a few minutes to work out what you're asking!  :)

Comment: You could add a 2nd event 

    `$('.cardButton').click($.debounce... );`
    `$(".cardButton").click(() => StartAnimationloader());`

Comment: @freedomn-m is this separate piece of code? o.o

Comment: @freedomn-m sec trying now

Comment: @freedomn-m holy hell it works! If you want - you can reply in form of answer so I can acceptt it! It works like a charm! :D

Comment: Can you also try: `$(".sel").click(function() { StartLoader(); $.debounce(1500, function() { .. }).call(); });`  possibly also `$(".sel").click(function() { StartLoader(); $.debounce(1500, function() { .. })(); })` - extra `()` after the `$.debounce(..)()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a 2nd (or more) event handler to the same element will fire both events (unless stopped) so you can create two actions by having two separate event handlers:

```
// existing debounce fire only after user stops clicking 
$('.cardButton').click($.debounce... ); 

// additional event will fire on every click
$(".cardButton").click(function() { StartAnimationloader() });
```